# Simulating a belongs_to_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a situation where in theory I would need to use a belongs_to_many relationship.  I have an Example model and a Sentence model.  Each example object has one sentence but these sentences are not necessarily unique.  So, for example, I could have two example models that each have one sentence that is the same sentence.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this in rails.  I tried using has_and_belongs_to_many, but ran into problems.  It seems that I only need the belongs_to :many part of that relationship. Ideally it would look something like this, but I know there is no belongs_to :many.

Example
  has_one :sentence
end

Sentence
  belongs_to_many :examples
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused by the direction your data is being accessed from. Here how your code should look like:

```
# app/models/example.rb
class Example
  belongs_to :sentence
end

# app/models/sentence.rb
class Sentence
  has_many :examples
end
```